# Glassfish 3: Calling method on ejb in ServletContextListener.contextDestroyed method leads to exception

Tags: glassfish, ejb, java-ee-6, servletcontextlistener

I have an @Singleton ejb which will be called in a ServletContextListener contextInitialized and contextDestroyed method. The call in the contextDestroyed method leads to an Exception:

javax.ejb.EJBException: Attempt to invoke when container is in STOPPED

It looks as if the contextDestroyed method is called after the container went down leaving
me with no chance to access any resources like my ejb.
Does anyone know if there is any way to know about application shutdown before the container
is down?

Thanx in advance.
Cheers, Sven

Answer (score 0):

You could use the `@PreDestroy` annotation on a method  directly in your `@Singleton` bean. Thus marked, the method will be called before the bean destruction, during the application shutdown.